# Encrypt data with PHP

Tags: php, crypt

I have this code:

```
    $token = $this->hextobin($dataEncrypt);
    $key = $this->key_192;
    $iv = $this->iv;
    $algorithm = 'xxxx';
    $mode = 'ecb'; //QUESTION!!!
    $td = mcrypt_module_open($algorithm, '', $mode, '') ;
    $iv = substr($iv, 0, mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td));
    $expected_key_size = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);
    $key = substr($key, 0, $expected_key_size);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $response = trim(mdecrypt_generic($td, $token), '');
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    $response = explode(XXXX,$response);
    return $response[0];
```

But reading the PHP documentation, specifically: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-ecb.php says that thus is obsolete and recommend mcrypt_generic() and mdecrypt_generic() for replacement.
My question is how to use these functions if you ask me the same way the open mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `mcrypt_generic()` is explained here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic.php

However, I would recommend the simpler API `mcrypt`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Example usage:

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, "secret key", "data to encrypt", MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

I noticed you had question marks on `ecb`. This is the "mode" for the encryption explained here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php

According to the PHP Docs:

- **MCRYPT_MODE_ECB** (electronic codebook) is suitable for random data, such as encrypting other keys. Since data there is short and random, the disadvantages of ECB have a favorable negative effect.
- **MCRYPT_MODE_CBC** (cipher block chaining) is especially suitable for encrypting files where the security is increased over ECB significantly.
- **MCRYPT_MODE_CFB** (cipher feedback) is the best mode for encrypting byte streams where single bytes must be encrypted.
- **MCRYPT_MODE_OFB** (output feedback, in 8bit) is comparable to CFB, but can be used in applications where error propagation cannot be tolerated. It's insecure (because it operates in 8bit mode) so it is not recommended to use it.
- **MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB** (output feedback, in nbit) is comparable to OFB, but more secure because it operates on the block size of the algorithm.
- **MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM** is an extra mode to include some stream algorithms like "WAKE" or "RC4".

**Update**
If your using the `CBC` mode, remember to set the `iv` like so:

```
$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
echo mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, "secret key", "data", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Comment: Hi, but use MCRYPT_MODE_CBC is secure?

Comment: depends on what your encrypting. I assume they are all secure to a certain extent. Some are more secure in certain situations that others I assume. What kind of data are you encrypting?

Comment: I try encrypt only text for example ids of my users what I put in $_SESSION['id_blablabla']

Comment: I guess ECB would be okay for this (I think), as it may fall under "random data", but if you want to be extra safe use CBC.